# Split and grab text before second hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following text string:

```
test-shirt-print
```

I want to filter the text string so that it only returns me:

```
test-shirt
```

Meaning that everything that comes after the second hyphen should be removed including the hyphen.

I am thinking that the solution could be to split on hyphen and somehow select the two first values, and combine them again.

I am unaware of which functionality is best practice to use here, I also thinking that if it would be possible to use a regular expression in order to be able to select everything before the second hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

> The `slice()` method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string.

and [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

> The `lastIndexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the last occurrence of the specified value, searching backwards from fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```js
var str = 'test-shirt-print';
var res = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf('-'));
console.log(res);
```

You can also use `split()` to take the first two items and join them:

```js
var str = 'test-shirt-print';
var res = str.split('-').slice(0,2).join('-');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split slice and join together to remove everything after the second hyphen

```js
var str = "test-shirt-print";
console.log(str.split("-").slice(0, 2).join('-'))
```